# allocating space for pointers in class fields

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble understanding when to allocate memory using new in a constructor (end freeing it using delete in the D'tor) when I have ptr field in my class. e.g.

```
class A {
    private:
    type* some_ptr;
    public:
    A(type* data):data(some_ptr);
    ~A();
}
```

or should it be:

```
class A {
    private:
    type* some_ptr;
    public:
    A(type* data) { some_ptr = new type(data) };
    ~A(type* data) { delete data };
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I assume you want to store the pointer given in the constructor in the member variable
- Given the class is not the one creating the data, the class should not delete it. Maybe the pointer will be used in some other places too.
- A destructor has never any parameters!

Try:

```
class A {
private:
    type* some_ptr;
public:
    A(type* data) : some_ptr(data) {};
    ~A() {};
}
```

Here is a list of things you might want to do:

Store a given pointer in a class:

```
class A {
private:
    int* class_ptr;
public:
    A(int* param_ptr) : class_ptr(param_ptr) {};
    ~A() {};
}

// Note: The Order is importand! 
// Deletion is the reverse from creation
void main() {
    int* int_ptr = new int(5);
    A* a = new A(int_ptr);

    delete a;
    delete int_ptr;
}
```

If you want to create a new pointer to some data in the constructor you can do it like this:

```
class A {
private:
    type* some_ptr;
public:
    A() : some_ptr(new type) {};
    ~A() { delete some_ptr; };
}
```

Or like this, if the creation is dependent on some other data:

```
class A {
private:
    type* some_ptr;
public:
    A(othertype param) : some_ptr(new type(param)) {};
    ~A() { delete some_ptr; };
}
```